# How to use Bootstrap "Display-3" on mobile screen size

Tags: bootstrap-4

I like how using "display-3" works on desktop. It looks great. But on mobile, some of the words get cut off. How do I make it "display-4-sm" or something like that for mobile? I'm not sure what the syntax or solution is.

```
<h1 class="d-sm-display-3   animation" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="1.1s">Blockchain at Virginia Tech</h1>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I checked the source code of your website and you are not using Bootstrap 5 but version 4.
In bootstrap 5 responsive fonts are enabled by default.

To enable responsive fonts in Bootstrap 4 you can do the following in your custom SCSS theme file:

`$enable-responsive-font-sizes: true !default;`

You could also write a custom class in CSS to change the font size on smaller screen sizes. For example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .display-3 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
}
```

---

In my knowledge there are **no** `sm`, `md` or `lg` classes for *headings* and *display headings*.

If you'd want to stick with Bootstrap classes only, you can make 2 div's in which you could use `d-md-block` and `d-sm-block` for example:

```
<h1 class="display-3 d-md-block d-none">Hello World!</h1>
<h1 class="display-5 d-sm-block d-md-none">Hello World!</h1>
```

However, I do not recommend that approach and would go for any of the first 2 solutions.